# Cannot roll back to old TensorFlow version on MacOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, macos-catalina

(I am a novice to Python and SO please be patient. If I use the wrong terminology, it is because I am coming from the background of Java/C)

I am trying to use the TensorFlow Slim model for image recognition and only realised late into the process that it was not compatible with TensorFlow 2 (It uses `'tensorflow.contrib'`)

However when I tried rolling back to version 1.14 using `pip3 install "tensorflow==1.14"` it throws the following error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14 (from versions: 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14`

This leaves me under the impression that either TensorFlow 1 has been removed from pip or that there is a more complex process behind rolling back

So if anyone knows how to roll back to 1.14 or any TensorFlow 1 version I would much appreciate it

I am running Python version 3.8.1 and TensorFlow version 2.2.0 on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What I might suggest here is do not downgrade your system's tensorflow to run a code, and it is generally better to use the most recent stable version of tensorflow instead use a virtual environment. You can do the following steps in your Mac Os terminal:

1. Install virtualenv(if you don't have it already)

   ```
    pip install virtualenv
   ```
2. Create a virtual environment

   ```
    virtualenv path/to/new/tf1_environment/
   ```
3. Activate the environment

   ```
    source path/to/new/tf1_environment/bin/activate
   ```
4. Install tensorflow version required for the code

   ```
    pip install tensorflow==1.14
   ```
5. Run the python code

   ```
    python3 my_script.py
   ```
6. To deactivate the environment just run

   ```
    deactivate
   ```

Comment: Cheers for answering! Unfortunately when I try running ```virtualenv ./env``` it just states that it can't find the command virtualenv. I have installed it using pip3  EDIT: And in any case - I do not believe this will solve the issue that pip3 does not recognise tensorflow 1.14 as a vlid version

Comment: I'm assuming that pip is up to date, use pip3 instead then

Comment: Neither of them seem to work :/ - virtualenv is still not recognised